# Is it safe to store per-request data on flask.request?

Tags: python, flask

Can the `flask.request` object be used similarly to `flask.g` to store per-request data?

I am writing a library that is compatible with both Flask and Django. I plan to store information on the request object in both cases. Can I safely store objects on the request, say `request.user`, with the assurance that it will not be shared between different requests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The request object is unique per request.

Typically `g` is used because it is an empty namespace specifically created for holding data during a request.

`request` is an internal object with existing meaning, although it is common for libraries to use it for storage, leaving `g` for "application level" data.