# In Python Flask: What are appropriate places to store data?

Tags: python, flask

According to the answer given in [Is it safe to store per-request data on flask.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571764/is-it-safe-to-store-per-request-data-on-flask-request) it seems that the `g` object is request-local (= has the lifetime of a single request). Maybe I misunderstood this answer, but the Flask documentation states that the `g` object would be global which seems to contradict this answer.

The documentation itself is a bit short about these details, so please would you mind to explain the details to the contexts and the global object `g`? Specifically to address the following questions:

1. In order to store data for the lifetime of a **single request**, how should that be done? (Using the `request` object, the `g` object or which kind of object?)
2. In order to store data for the **lifetime of an application**, how should that be done? (Using the `app` object, the `g` object or which kind of object?)
3. Flask could be used in a multi-process environment. Is it correct to assume that in such a mode of operation there will be **multiple application-wide objects**? (This would imply that all of these `app` or `g` objects then need to be initialized individually for the lifetime of each worker process.)
4. Related to question 3: If I require an application wide, single singleton-like object that provides services to a Flask web application, it is mandatory to factor out this service into an external process? (Within a multi-process mode of operation there won't be a single singleton-like instance?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*In order to store data for the lifetime of a **single request**, how should that be done?*

The `g` object is designed for this. The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.g) states:

> Flask provides you with a special object that ensures it is only valid for the active request and that will return different values for each request.

Although the documentation refers to `g` as "global", that's not really accurate - "thread-global" would be better.

*In order to store data for the **lifetime of an application**, how should that be done?*

I think the answer to this question answers this as well (or better) than I could:
[Preserving global state in a flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277280/preserving-global-state-in-a-flask-application)

*Flask could be used in a multi-process environment. Is it correct to assume that in such a mode of operation there will be multiple application-wide objects? (This would imply that all of these app or g objects then need to be initialized individually for the lifetime of each worker process.)*

In a multi-process environment, each request is handled as a seperate thread, and `g` is intialized and destroyed on a per-request basis, so there will be as many concurrent `g` object as threads - though each thread can only see it's own. In most scenarios I suspect there should only ever one `app` object, an instance of the Flask() class created by the programmer, i.e. `app = Flask(__name__)` or similar.

[Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/) and [Application Dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appdispatch/) are two way of having "multiple" application objects, in as far as you have multiple applications running concurrently.

Comment: Let me point out that in one detail you provide me with the same confusion as the answer I referred to: The `g` object seems to be related to an application context so it would maintain data for longer than a single request. That's one of the reasons why I'm asking part 1 of my question. Answer 19277280 states that I have `g` on a request basis. That confuses me as well: In the Flask documentation I find an example about storing open data base connections in `g`, which then would make no sense.

Comment: Do you mean the example at the end of http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/? The database connection there only exists for the lifetime of the context.

Comment: I believe this answer is no longer correct. The documentation link provided no longer works and the documentation I found (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.g) states that as of version 0.10 'g' is attached to the application context instead of the request context, although, confusingly it still says that "This is a good place to store resources during a request."